# Is there really something wrong with this Edit attempt?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, rejected-edits

I'm referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926336/disable-keybord-shortcut-on-notepad) question.

The original poster confirmed that Notepad++, one of the original tags, had nothing to do with the problem, which was instead due to Windows IME.
My edit was: Remove [notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b) tag, add [ime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ime) and [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) tags.

My first edit attempt only stated in the comment *"Changed tags"*. It was rejected this way:

> - Mouser reviewed this 12 mins ago: Reject
>
>   - This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.
> - Ricardo Peres reviewed this 36 mins ago: Approve
> - Darren Young reviewed this 51 mins ago: Reject
>
>   - This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.
> - Rufus L reviewed this 58 mins ago: Reject
>
>   - This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

The thread is made just of 2 lines of question, 4 of already accepted answer and other 3 lines of comments, a 5 seconds glimpse at it would make it obvious to anyone that the edit is correct, in my eyes.

However I decided to go out of my way and also include a more expansive explanation in my second attempt, to see if this would change the outcome in any way: *"Changed tags so as to precisely describe the problem, initially mistakenly attributed to Notepad++"*.

But it ended in a similar way:

> - worldofjr reviewed this 29 mins ago: Reject
>
>   - This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question. Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains.
> - Peter Pei Guo reviewed this 55 mins ago: Reject
>
>   - This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question. Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains.
> - Tomas Petricek reviewed this 1 hour ago: Reject
>
>   - This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question. Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains.

I wonder, am I stupid in thinking that my edit was correct and *"This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question. Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains."* or *"This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability."* describe exactly the opposite of what it tried to do, or is it just that the reviewers don't care to even have a look at the thread before voting?

Comment: .. But you left it in the title (along with an obvious typo). I must say, personally I'd not have rejected the edit, although I also may have left a comment for the author that it's totally unrelated to Notepad++.

Comment: @Jongware Yes I left it in the title, and it was indeed a deliberate decision, because there are no other citations to it in the post, deleting it would have rendered the post hard to understand and it would have probably "deviated from the original intent of the post", and most of all it is indeed useful to cite Notepad++, because it often does have a role in this problem in that it has shortcuts that include the Windows IME ones, so people easily fall into it while using Notepad++, do the same mistake in thinking it is its fault, and so search for Notepad++ shortcuts issues.

Comment: @Jongware btw I did not notice the keybord typo until now... so that was my fault? :)

Comment: @Jongware regarding the comment I was the author of the answer, and in it I said 'probably' because really I couldn't be absolutely sure that Notepad++, maybe via some strange plug-in, had nothing to do with the problem

Comment: If the question was not about Notepad++ (which you've said it was not, and you removed the Notepad++ tag), it was inappropriate to leave the title unedited. If the tag is not applicable because the question isn't about that topic, and you remove the tag for that reason, you should edit the question title as well to do the same. If you can justify leaving it in the title, then you were probably wrong about removing the tag.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm not sure if there's a strict semantic role for tags and titles on this site, but I have the feeling that tags should only be attached when they are unquestionably very relevant for the question; I said that Notepad++ is often involved in the problem, but probably so are tens of other softwares that I don't know about. Should all softwares that have shortcuts including alt+shift be included as tags?
(continues...)

Comment: @KenWhite In my opinion leaving the title and the original post as they were gives the most likelihood that someone with the exact same problem as the original poster, namely incurring into the keyboard map change while using Notepad++, find the question, but the tag... well it seemed too much to me. But actually it wouldn't make much difference to me, it was important to add the IME and Windows tags, but the Notepad++ could stay without making much harm. Maybe I was just infected by the deletion/rejection/inconsiderateness craze that seems to pervade this site.
(continues...)

Comment: @KenWhite This was what seemed the best balance to me, anyway.

Comment: I was only stating what seemed to me to be the reason your edits were rejected (the apparent inconsistency - if the tag is deemed removable, the title should have been edited, and if the title is applicable as is then the tag probably should remain). I doubt I would have rejected the edit, although I certainly would have improved it.

Comment: @KenWhite Well the reasons are clearly stated, they don't seem to be related to what you said; maybe just the first one ( _"deviates from the original intent of the post"_ ) might be related to the removal of the tag, but it's very hard to deduce that from what is written; I imagine that is a canned comment, but I read that it is possible to write a custom review comment, so if the problem was the tag removal he could have written that.
You might have a very good reason to reject an edit, but if you declare another reason you are still wrong (and in my view you should be punished in some way).

Comment: You asked, I offered an opinion as to why it might have happened. I really didn't intend to start a debate; I'm a little confused as to why you asked for an explanation and then attack people for trying to offer one. IMO, there's a major inconsistency in the edit you proposed, and that **might be** why it was rejected both times. ("I'm removing the tag for <this thing> because it doesn't apply, but it still applies in the subject so I'll leave it alone" doesn't make sense **to me**, and maybe not to others.) Why should we *punish people* for doing what they think is right?

Comment: @KenWhite I'm sorry if you felt attacked, I must have expressed myself badly. You (two) are being helpful. My intent was mainly to understand better how the site worked.
I think that people that moderate manifestly with little care should be punished, because they provoke a lot of frustration, loss of time and damage to the site's value.
Anyhow this is probably off-topic here, and I should get some sleep. If you want I'll be glad to continue the discussion tomorrow, possibly in some other section.

Comment: hey gbr, would you please add a link to the suggested edit. This will help quite a bit more.

Comment: @gideon I didn't think about that, here they are:
http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6755788
http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6756234